# how to decode gps binary messages using gpsd in linux for u-blox neo8n gps engine

Tags: linux, gps, gpsd

is gpsd able to decode u-blox binary messages or not? i particularly need the UBX-NAV messages.
if it doesn't what do you recommend to use instead?(a linux based one plz)

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo su`
2. `dmesg | grep tty`. It's possible to see any below device name:

   ```
   /dev/ttyUSB0
   /dev/ttyACM0
   /dev/ttyUSB1
   /dev/ttyACM1
   ```

   If device name contains "USB" try `ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/ttyACM1`.

   *Note: Every disconnect port get changed Nameport!*
3. [Build some control files](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=168435).
4. Open new terminal and enjoy: `cgps`.